# Query dynamodb table by primary key

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries, amazon-dynamodb-index

I'm having problems creating a simple query request. [Here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB/DocumentClient.html#query-property) they show an example of how to do a query using the global secondary index. Now in this case, I just have the primary key, and I'd like to query from my table. This is currently the error that I'm getting:

`Query condition missed key schema element: id`

Here is what I'm currently trying:

```
var params = {
  TableName : "XactRemodel-7743-DynamoDBImagesTable-8183NQ0UG0Y5",
  KeyConditionExpression: 'HashKey = :hkey',
  ExpressionAttributeValues: {
    ':hkey': event.projectId
  }
};
documentClient.query(params, function(err, data) {
   if (err) {
     console.log(err)
   } else {
     console.log(data);
   }
});
```

I know that in the example they used "indexName" which corresponds to the secondary indexes name. They Key Schema doesn't seem to have such an [attribute](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-dynamodb-keyschema.html).

This is what my table looks like defined in a YAML file:

```
DynamoDBImagesTable:
Type: AWS::DynamoDB::Table
Properties:
  BillingMode: PAY_PER_REQUEST
  SSESpecification:
    SSEEnabled: true
  PointInTimeRecoverySpecification:
    PointInTimeRecoveryEnabled: true
  AttributeDefinitions:
    - AttributeName: id
      AttributeType: S
    - AttributeName: companyId
      AttributeType: S
    - AttributeName: lastModified
      AttributeType: S
  KeySchema:
    - AttributeName: id
      KeyType: HASH
  GlobalSecondaryIndexes:
    - IndexName: companyId-index
      KeySchema:
        - AttributeName: companyId
          KeyType: HASH
        - AttributeName: lastModified
          KeyType: RANGE
      Projection:
        ProjectionType: ALL
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is trying to query by primary key named `HashKey`:

```
KeyConditionExpression: 'HashKey = :hkey',
```

However your primary key is named `id` which is what the error message is pointing out. So change that line to:

```
KeyConditionExpression: 'id = :hkey',
```

Comment: You know, looking at it now seems so obvious... ‍♂️, for some reason I thought that was referring to the type of key. Well, thanks so much!

Comment: Would I be wrong to suggest that this is a case where you should really use [`get()`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB/DocumentClient.html#get-property) and not `query()`?  Or does it matter?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot looking back at this, I believe you're right. Get() should do the work, and it's a little more simple